# streamwriter : csv file

Tags: c#, winforms, csv, .net-4.0

I use `StreamWriter` to write data to a csv file. When I open the csv file using Excel, everything is fine except that some of the cells have the hash symbol instead of the data written to the cell. This data, however, becomes visible on increasing the cell size. Is there any way to overcome this problem of the hash(`#`) symbols without having to manually increase cell sizes.

```
int cols;
//open file 
//StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter(@"O:\C_2013_MRO_Software Database\Manpowerdata.csv");
StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Manpowerdata.csv");

//determine the number of columns and write columns to file 
var dgvStock = dataGridView3;
cols = dgvStock.Columns.Count;
for (int i = 0; i < cols - 1; i++)
{
    wr.Write(dgvStock.Columns[i].Name.ToString().ToUpper() + ",");
}
wr.WriteLine();

//write rows to excel file
for (int i = 0; i < (dgvStock.Rows.Count - 1); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
    {
        if (dgvStock.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value != null)
        {
            wr.Write(dgvStock.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value + ",");
        }
        else
        {
            wr.Write(",");
        }
    }
    wr.WriteLine();
}

//close file
wr.Close();
```

Comment: Code please? What have you tried? Do you mean # as the hash symbol?

Comment: I believe there are some formatting options (rather than cell sizing) which should resolve this issue.

Comment: I'm going to wildly assume that OP means that the when they open the CSV file in Excel, the default column-width is too small for the value.

Comment: So your program outputs correct CSV data, you import it into Excel, and Excel renders it in an ugly way? If that is the case, then your problem is with Excel, not your CSV-writing program.

Comment: The OP may not recognize the distinction between importing into Excel and opening directly (say in Notepad).  Excel makes it look *very much* like you opened the file unchanged when you open a csv.

Answer (score 4):

When viewed in MS Excel (and other spreadsheet programs), data which does not fit in a cell [will be replaced](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/923616) with `########`.  This does not indicate anything about the underlying CSV data.